# Using system() to Run LibreOffice / soffice on OSX

Tags: excel, macos, matlab, libreoffice, soffice

I'm running MATLAB 2013a on OSX and am attempting to convert a .xlsx file to a .pdf using MATLAB script. After determining that this couldn't be achieved using MATLAB alone, I downloaded LibreOffice to help me out. Running the following code in Mac Terminal works perfectly:

`/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /Users/dwm8/Desktop/ /Users/dwm8/Desktop/box_copy.xlsx`

This code saves the file `box_copy.xlsx` as a .pdf on my desktop. However, when I try running the same code in MATLAB using `system()`:

`system('/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /Users/dwm8/Desktop/ /Users/dwm8/Desktop/box_copy.xlsx')`

the .pdf does not get saved, and I get the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/libcurl.4.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvcllo.dylib
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: libvcllo.dylib requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
>   /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /Users/dwm8/Desktop/ /Users/dwm8/Desktop/box_copy.xlsx: Trace/breakpoint trap`

Additionally, this error window pops up:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this error?